# ASP.NET MVC Model Design and migrations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

I'm preparing to start designing an ASP.NET MVC web application and plan to use the model designer to create objects which models will then be automatically and transprently created by ASP.NET using a specified database system (SQLite, or MSSQL, or other...).

I tried to find information about that, but nothing really clear for me as I am french, so sorry if my question were already asked somewhere. I would be very grateful for any help.

So the problem is, when I will need to migrate objects and data after adding features, improved the application workflow, etc..., how will ASP.NET MVC can manage the migration ? I guess I would need to use some migration framework such as MigratorDotNet ? But problem with this one for example : it needs to specify fields and tables as migration instructions, while ASP.NET MVC is intended to manage it all transparently.

I hope I explained well.
Thank you very much for your help !

EDIT :
What I wanted to ask, specifically and may be more simply is :
Is it possible to make my application model migration quite automatically based on comparison between previous and new model design made through the model designer ? If yes, how ? Thanks a lot !

EDIT 2 :
I think I found some answer on "Step 5: Changing our Model" of this page :
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx using Database.SetInitializer() call on the Application_Start() handler.

EDIT 3:
I may have finally found my solution, the Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack explained here : http://blog.nakedobjects.net/?p=137

Did anyone already try and use it in production ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think this is the solution I will adopt :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/02/08/entity-designer-database-generation-power-pack.aspx

I hope this will be usefull to anyone in the future !

Comment: Hi Virrea is this the solution that you are still using?

Comment: Hi, I used it at the beginning and would probably still use it. But the project is paused.